# Storing time ranges in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking for a good way to store data associated with a time range, in order to be able to efficiently retrieve it later.

Each entry of data can be simplified as `(start time, end time, value)`. I will need to later retrieve all the entries which fall inside a `(x, y)` range. In SQL, the query would be something like

`SELECT value FROM data WHERE starttime <= x AND endtime >= y`

Can you suggest a structure for the data in Cassandra which would allow me to perform such queries efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an oddly difficult thing to model efficiently.

I think using Cassandra's secondary indexes (along with a dummy indexed value which is unfortunately still needed at the moment) is your best option.  You'll need to use one row per event with at least three columns: 'start', 'end', and 'dummy'.  Create a secondary index on each of these.  The first two can be LongType and the last can be BytesType.  See [this post on using secondary indexes](http://www.riptano.com/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes) for more details.  Since you have to use an EQ expression on at least one column for a secondary index query (the unfortunate requirement I mentioned), the EQ will be on 'dummy', which can always set to 0.  (This means that the EQ index expression will match every row and essentially be a no-op.)  You can store the rest of the event data in the row alongside start, end, and dummy.

In [pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa), a Python Cassandra client, your query would look like this:

```
from pycassa.index import *
start_time = 12312312000
end_time = 12312312300
start_exp = create_index_expression('start', start_time, GT)
end_exp = create_index_expression('end', end_time, LT)
dummy_exp = create_index_expression('dummy', 0, EQ)
clause = create_index_clause([start_exp, end_exp, dummy_exp], count=1000)
for result in entries.get_indexed_slices(clause):
    # do stuff with result
```

There should be something similar in other clients.

The alternative that I considered first involved OrderPreservingPartitioner, which is almost always a Bad Thing.  For the index, you would use the start time as the row key and the finish time as the column name.  You could then perform a range slice with start_key=start_time and column_finish=finish_time.  This would scan every row after the start time and only return those with columns before the finish_time.  Not very efficient, and you have to do a big multiget, etc.  The built-in secondary index approach is better because nodes will only index local data and most of the boilerplate indexing code is handled for you.