# Cassandra, working with start and end time ranges

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to track "reservations" with cassandra?

Basically, most of my queries will involve a `start_time` and an `end_time` where I will want to find all the reservations that intersect that time.

My schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    calendar_id text,
    uid text,
    start_time timestamp,
    end_time timestamp,
    dummy text,
    payload text,
    PRIMARY KEY (calendar_id, start_time, end_time, dummy)
);
```

I've entered some data, like this:

```
  INSERT INTO events
      (calendar_id, start_time, end_time, uid, dummy, payload)
      VALUES ('cal1', '2016-07-25T12:30:00-06', '2016-07-25T13:30:00-06', 'event1', '0', '{"description": "test"}');
```

and I am trying a query like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM events
      WHERE calendar_id = 'cal1'
      AND dummy = '0'
      AND start_time <= '2016-07-25T13:30:00-06' 
      AND end_time >= '2016-07-25T12:00:00-06';
```

and I get an error like this:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering column "end_time" cannot be restricted (preceding column "start_time" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"
```

I *think* it can be done, because it seems so in this SO question: [Storing time ranges in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667040/storing-time-ranges-in-cassandra)

However, the schema is not posted and we aren't using pycassa, and I can't seem to figure out how to map it to CQL.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There is very good blog post on DataStax site explaining in detail what you can use in WHERE clause and why are the restrictions in place. Check [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause). In summary  multi-column slice restrictions are allowed on the last set of clustering columns being restricted.